# Leaving out the last semicolon of a CSS block?

Tags: css

Can it result in browsers break after minification?
This is how my code looks like...

```
#myElement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}
#myElement2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

#myElement3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}
```

Comment: let an actual tool worry about minifying. omitting one character here and there is a waste of time when a tool can do a better job with less effort

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change it to:

```
#myElement, #myElement2, #myElement3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I just add it as an example. The main thing is a semicolon at the end of the CSS block. is it mandatory to semicolon at the end??